# How to set Qdialog to have a fixed height as small as possible and an expending width in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qsizepolicy

I have a Qdialog with a horizontal layout and a couple of elements. Now, I want the height to be fixed at its minimal possible size (while the width is still resizeable).

There are a couple of properties I can set, for example:

- `sizePolicy`, `minimumSize`, `maximumSize`, `baseSize`, `layoutSizeConstraint`

I tried to understand how the values interact and a couple of combinations but none got me what I want.

For example, I can enter the smallest `Height` possible in `maximumSize`, in my case `178`, and set the Vertical Policy in `sizePolicy` to `Fixed`. But then it is only fixed to a small range: I can still resize the dialog's height slightly to make it slightly smaller.

Comment: try with `dialog.setFixedHeight(dialog.sizeHint().height());`

Comment: Thanks. That actually works. So the correct answer is: "You cannot do this with Qt Creator"?

Comment: Yes, I have posted an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This type of tasks can not be done with Qt Designer, the minimum size if you use layouts is the `sizeHint()`, for example in your case the solution is:

```
dialog.setFixedHeight(dialog.sizeHint().height());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set minimumSize.Height and maximumSize.Height with same values

or

Just set fixed height in code

```
Dialog dialog;
dialog.setFixedHeight(dialog.height());
dialog.exec();
```

Comment: For me it works fine. Maybe you set maximumSize.Height less then possible for current layout. Do you set maximumSize/minimumSize in design or in code?

Comment: I set it in design. But the smallest number I can enter there seems to be larger than the minimum I can resize it to when compiled. In any case, setting a fixed number there seems wrong to me. Since Qt works cross platform the smallest possible size might differ from platform to platform, or?

Comment: look at dialog.setFixedHeight()

Comment: setFixedHeight() only takes an integer so it seems to have the same problem (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight). Under setFixedSize() setSizeConstraint() is mentioned as fixing size "based on its contents". Unfortunately, this only takes one value so no independent height and width settings there it seems. So no luck for now.